# WCF calling webservices parameters returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, .net-3.5

I have this webservice

```
 [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadReceipt?CompanyCode={CompanyCode}&FileName={FileName}&FileContent={FileContent}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
            RestResponseInfo<bool> UploadReceipt(string CompanyCode, string FileName, string FileContent);
```

And i am calling it like this
[image]

Then after it will call this method

```
public RestResponseInfo<bool> UploadReceipt(string CompanyCode, string FileName, string FileContent)
        {

}
```

But when i see this parameters by inspecting debugger its returning null value i am very much stuck into this from 5 hours ........

**I also used advance rest service from chrome but still have this issues**

Comment: @Uriil so i do not get you?

Comment: Method is done to post still receiving empty parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking i mark that
I am passing

```
<form runat="server" method="post" action="http://localhost:37542/AccountService.svc/UploadReceipt">
```

Which should be

```
 <form runat="server" method="post" action="http://localhost:37542/AccountService.svc/UploadReceipt?CompanyCode=1&FileName=Test&FileContent=/9j/4AAQ">
```

Any ways thanks for your support :)